# How do I install an app on a device running ubuntu touch?

Tags: installation, application-development, ubuntu-touch

I've built the sample app for ubuntu touch and I've got a device running the preview.

So how do I put the app on the device?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Qt Creator**: Connect your Ubuntu Touch Device through usb open your project and simply press `Ctrl+F12`.

This works only if you have once installed ssh-server on the device.

Alternatively you can do it **manually**. Copy the necessary files (*.qml and *.desktop) to the device and start the application via ssh

```
qmlscene --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/qmlscene.desktop YourApp.qml
```

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_SDK_Alpha)

Comment: Is there a fuller example. I'm new to ubuntu development and I don't even have a .desktop file

Comment: Then I would suggest you create a new project in Qt Creator and take the qml file from the sample app. (Are you talking about Currency Converter?) Then connect your device and start it via Ctrl+F12. And don't think about *.desktop at all. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Well I've launched the Currency Converter with Ctrl+F12, but when I leave the app I cannot get back to it and Ctrl+F12 isn't restarting it

Comment: Well maybe you're using a daily build? You might have to be a little patient with the system as there is heavy work still going on. If you cannot close the app you might have to kill it via ssh.

Comment: how should closing the app work?

Comment: I just notice that you cannot open the HUD. Should come up by swiping from the bottom and releasing the swipe on the magnifying glass. In this case you cannot close from the gui. Maybe add a button with this method `onClicked: { Qt.quit(); }`

Comment: Thanks for that. Also my app doesn't appear in the list of running apps